Baker's percentage symbol -- % in a loaf using TikZ
First, a little background.
Professional bakers (and, increasingly, bread baking enthusuasts generally as well) always weigh everything, particularly flour which is a highly variable substance: a cup (a volume measure) may weigh anything from a little over 3 ounces to a bit less than 5 ounces depending on how it is measured. It has become common for recipes using flour (bread, pastry) to specify ingredients by weight and baker's percentages. A baker's percentage (BP) is the percentage of the weight of a particular ingredient and the weight of the flour.  Modernist Bread (https://modernistbread.com) employs a useful notation for BP:

Uses can be found in recipe tables at (https://modernistcuisineshop.com/products/modernist-bread-at-home), of which the following is an excerpt:

This also shows the utility of the BP symbol as apposed to the usual % symbol. (For what it's worth, one of the many uses of BP is the percentage of liquid's weight relative to the weight of the flour: This gives an immediate indication of how sticky, or not, the dough will be -- important indication of the manner in which the dough will be handled and the texture of the finished product. In this case 63.79, indicating a relatively tight, non-sticky dough.)
To create the loaf shape, I started with the following skeleton:

Then applied instances of [in=...,out=...]:

Close, but there are two problems: 1) a tiny disconnect at D and 2) a subtle dimple at F:

Clearly, there are some aspects of [in=...,out=...] that I don't understand. Thanks in advance for any insights
All of the above was generated with:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[%showframe,
    papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,tikz}

\newsavebox{\bpbox}

\newlength{\loafdomeht}
\newlength{\loafsideht}
\newlength{\puffht}
\newlength{\loafhalfwd}

\def\sideslope{97}% angles BAI HIA
\def\myloose{0.75}
\def\domeangle{30}% angle between CD and DE; between EF and FG

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\loafdomeht}{0.075in}% height above D--F
\setlength{\loafsideht}{0.5in}%% AB=HI
\setlength{\puffht}{0.1in}% =BC=CD=FG=GH
\setlength{\loafhalfwd}{0.325in}%=0.5AI

The skeleton:

\tikz[baseline,every node/.style={font=\tiny}]{%
    \draw (0,0)node[left]{A}
        -- ++(\sideslope:\loafsideht)node[left]{B}
        -- ++(-\puffht,\puffht)node[left]{C}
        -- ++(\puffht,\puffht)node[left]{D}
        -- ++(\loafhalfwd,\loafdomeht)node[above]{E}
        -- ++(\loafhalfwd,-\loafdomeht)node[right]{F}
        -- ++(\puffht,-\puffht)node[right]{G}
        -- ++(-\puffht,-\puffht)node[right]{H}
        -- ++(-\sideslope:\loafsideht)node[right]{I}
        -- cycle;
}

\bigskip

Thickened and rounded:

\smallskip

\tikz[baseline]{%
    \draw[line width=2pt] (0,0)
        -- ++(\sideslope:\loafsideht)to[out=160,in=270]
        ++(-\puffht,\puffht) to[in=\domeangle,out=90]
        ++(\puffht,\puffht)to[in=180,out=\domeangle,looseness=\myloose]
        ++(\loafhalfwd,\loafdomeht)to[out=0,in={180-\domeangle},looseness=\myloose]
        ++(\loafhalfwd,-\loafdomeht)to[out=-\domeangle,in=90]
        ++(\puffht,-\puffht)to[out=270,in=30]
        ++(-\puffht,-\puffht)[rounded corners=0.2em]
        -- ++(-\sideslope:\loafsideht)
        -- cycle;
}

\bigskip

The problems:

\tikz[baseline]{%
    \draw[line width=2pt] (0,0)
        -- ++(\sideslope:\loafsideht)to[out=160,in=270]
        ++(-\puffht,\puffht) to[in=\domeangle,out=90]
        ++(\puffht,\puffht)node[draw,circle,red]{}to[in=180,out=\domeangle,looseness=\myloose]
        ++(\loafhalfwd,\loafdomeht)to[out=0,in={180-\domeangle},looseness=\myloose]
        ++(\loafhalfwd,-\loafdomeht)node[circle,draw,blue]{}to[out=-\domeangle,in=90]
        ++(\puffht,-\puffht)to[out=270,in=30]
        ++(-\puffht,-\puffht)[rounded corners=0.2em]
        -- ++(-\sideslope:\loafsideht)
        -- cycle;
}

\sbox{\bpbox}{% for repeated use in text, changing inches to ems:
    \setlength{\loafdomeht}{0.075em}%
    \setlength{\loafsideht}{0.5em}%
    \setlength{\puffht}{0.1em}%
    \setlength{\loafhalfwd}{0.325em}%
    \tikz[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt]{%
        \draw[line width=0.04em] (0,0)coordinate(A)
        -- ++(\sideslope:\loafsideht)to[out=150,in=270]
        ++(-\puffht,\puffht) to[in=\domeangle,out=90]
        ++(\puffht,\puffht)to[in=180,out=\domeangle,looseness=\myloose]
        ++(\loafhalfwd,\loafdomeht)to[out=0,in={180-\domeangle},looseness=\myloose]coordinate(E)
        ++(\loafhalfwd,-\loafdomeht)to[out=-\domeangle,in=90]
        ++(\puffht,-\puffht)to[out=270,in=30]
        ++(-\puffht,-\puffht)[rounded corners=0.075em]
        -- ++(-\sideslope:\loafsideht)coordinate(I)
        -- cycle;
        \node[font=\scriptsize] at (current bounding box.center) {\%};
    }%
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\bp}{}{\usebox{\bpbox}}

\begingroup
\small
\begin{tabular}{llll}
INGREDIENTS& WEIGHT& VOLUME& \bp\\\hline
High-gluten flour*&250\thinspace &2 cups&100\\
Butter, cold&145\thinspace g&⅔ cup&50\\
$\cdots$\\
Eggs, cold&120\thinspace g& 2 ea&41.38\\
Whole milk, cold&65\thinspace g&¼ cup& 22.41\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\footnotesize*\emph{Be sure your bread flour is 12.5\% to 13\% protein.}

\end{document}

Update
As I mentioned in a comment, @daleif had mentioned Bézier curves and that prompted me to wonder if the Hobby tikzlibrary could be used. Though this is the very first time I have used it, it appears to do the trick very nicely indeed:

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[%showframe,
    papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,hobby}

\newsavebox{\bpbox}

\newlength{\loafdomeht}
\newlength{\loafsideht}
\newlength{\puffht}
\newlength{\loafhalfwd}

\def\sideslope{97}% angles BAI HIA

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\setlength{\loafdomeht}{0.075in}% height above D--F
\setlength{\loafsideht}{0.5in}%% AB=HI
\setlength{\puffht}{0.1in}% =BC=CD=FG=GH
\setlength{\loafhalfwd}{0.325in}%=0.5AI

\tikz[baseline,use Hobby shortcut]{%
    %% set the drawing points
    \path (0,0)coordinate(A)
        -- ++(\sideslope:\loafsideht)coordinate(B)
        -- ++(-\puffht,\puffht)coordinate(C)
        -- ++(\puffht,\puffht)coordinate(D)
        -- ++(\loafhalfwd,\loafdomeht)coordinate(E)
        -- ++(\loafhalfwd,-\loafdomeht)coordinate(F)
        -- ++(\puffht,-\puffht)coordinate(G)
        -- ++(-\puffht,-\puffht)coordinate(H)
        -- ++(-\sideslope:\loafsideht)coordinate(I)
        -- cycle;
        \coordinate (M) at ($(A)!0.5!(I)$);% find the middle of the loaf
        \coordinate (X) at (M |- E);% locate the dome top middle
        \draw (A) -- (B) .. (C) .. (D) .. (X) .. (F) .. (G) .. (H) -- (I) -- cycle;
}

%% Notice the use of **em** units for lengths: this ensures that if the font size is changed
%% the symbol will still look as it should relative to surrounding text.
\sbox{\bpbox}{% for repeated use in text, changing inches to ems:
    \setlength{\loafdomeht}{0.075em}%
    \setlength{\loafsideht}{0.5em}%
    \setlength{\puffht}{0.1em}%
    \setlength{\loafhalfwd}{0.325em}%
    \tikz[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,use Hobby shortcut]{%
    \path (0,0)coordinate(A)
        -- ++(\sideslope:\loafsideht)coordinate(B)
        -- ++(-\puffht,\puffht)coordinate(C)
        -- ++(\puffht,\puffht)coordinate(D)
        -- ++(\loafhalfwd,\loafdomeht)coordinate(E)
        -- ++(\loafhalfwd,-\loafdomeht)coordinate(F)
        -- ++(\puffht,-\puffht)coordinate(G)
        -- ++(-\puffht,-\puffht)coordinate(H)
        -- ++(-\sideslope:\loafsideht)coordinate(I)
        -- cycle;
        \coordinate (M) at ($(A)!0.5!(I)$);% find the middle of the loaf
        \coordinate (X) at (M |- E);% locate the dome top middle
        \draw (A) -- (B) .. (C) .. (D) .. (X) .. (F) .. (G) .. (H) -- (I) -- cycle;
        \node[font=\scriptsize] at (current bounding box.center) {\%};
    }%
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\bp}{}{\usebox{\bpbox}}

\begingroup
\small
\begin{tabular}{llll}
INGREDIENTS& WEIGHT& VOLUME& \bp\\\hline
High-gluten flour*&290\thinspace &2 cups&100\\
Butter, cold&145\thinspace g&⅔ cup&50\\
$\cdots$\\
Eggs, cold&120\thinspace g& 2 ea&41.38\\
Whole milk, cold&65\thinspace g&¼ cup& 22.41\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\footnotesize*\emph{Be sure your bread flour is 12.5\% to 13\% protein.}

\end{document}

Update 2
Just a note to demonstrate the advantages of using font-based measurements (the em) in constructing grraphics intended to be used in text. Though the Hobby curves impose a computation penalty, the symbol is generally not used frequently so can be regenerated afresh each time it is used.
One change here: The width of the loaf is now dependent on the width of the % character.

\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[%showframe,
    papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,hobby}

\newsavebox{\bpbox}

\newlength{\loafdomeht}
\newlength{\loafsideht}
\newlength{\puffht}
\newlength{\loafhalfwd}

\def\sideslope{97}% angles BAI HIA

%% Notice the use of **em** units for lengths: this ensures that if the document
%% font size is changed the symbol will still look as it should relative to surrounding text.
\NewDocumentCommand{\bp}{s o}{% *=?; #2=?; Tweak any or all of the following to suit:
    \setlength{\loafdomeht}{0.065em}%
    \setlength{\loafsideht}{0.45em}%
    \setlength{\puffht}{0.125em}%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\fontsize{0.7em}{0.7em}\selectfont\%}% <--scriptfont size relative to current>
    \setlength{\loafhalfwd}{0.7\wd0}%
    \smash{%
        \tikz[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,use Hobby shortcut]{%
            \path (0,0)coordinate(A)
                -- ++(\sideslope:\loafsideht)coordinate(B)
                -- ++(-\puffht,\puffht)coordinate(C)
                -- ++(\puffht,\puffht)coordinate(D)
                -- ++(\loafhalfwd,\loafdomeht)coordinate(E)
                -- ++(\loafhalfwd,-\loafdomeht)coordinate(F)
                -- ++(\puffht,-\puffht)coordinate(G)
                -- ++(-\puffht,-\puffht)coordinate(H)
                -- ++(-\sideslope:\loafsideht)coordinate(I)
                -- cycle;
            \coordinate (M) at ($(A)!0.5!(I)$);% find the middle of the loaf
            \coordinate (X) at (M |- E);% locate the dome top middle
            \draw[line width=0.04em] (A) -- (B) .. (C) .. (D) .. (X) ..
                (F) .. (G) .. (H) -- (I) -- cycle;
            \node[font=\scriptsize] at ($(X)!0.5!(M)$) {\box0};
        }%
    }%
}%

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\foreach \S in {tiny,scriptsize,footnotesize,small,normalsize,large,Large,LARGE,huge,Huge}{%
    \S: \begingroup\csname \S \endcsname\bp\par\endgroup
}

\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
This is a bunch of bla bla bla to take up a certain amount of useless space. 
This is some text X\,\bp\,X\ with a symbol in it.\footnote{A symbol \bp\ in a footnote: Note that the symbol has scaled with the prevailing font size in this footnote.}
This is a bunch of bla bla bla to take up a certain amount of useless space.
This is a bunch of bla bla bla to take up a certain amount of useless space.
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}

Followup
Taking a suggestion from @MS-SPO and @daleif, I have omitted the points D and F (see original “skeleton”) -- this has necessitated a revision of some of the definitions. This has also made the routine quicker.
Use \bpsetup[<keyval options>] to change several drawing parameters; \bpsetup[bpnoisy] will write to the log file what is happening each time \bp is used. The \bp macro is now a bit smarter -- if the symbol has been previously created, it is used; \bp* forces regeneration -- useful if the font and/or size has changed; \bp[<stuff>] adds stuff to the log file for that use of \bp.
\documentclass[]{article}
%quick Hobby shortcut: sizes < \normalsize gives bad shapes; \tiny gives division by 0 error; + Drop 'D' and 'F' from \draw, though not from the skeleton -- requires fiddling with basic lengths
\usepackage[%showframe,
    papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,tikz,keyval,multicol}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,hobby}

\newsavebox{\bpbox}

\newlength{\loafdomeht}
\newlength{\loafsideht}
\newlength{\puffht}
\newlength{\loafhalfwd}
\newif\ifbpnoisy
%% tweak any or all to suit:
\def\pcscale{0.7}
\def\loafwdscale{0.525}
\def\loafsidescale{0.375}
\def\linewidthscale{0.04}

\def\sideslope{97}% angles BAI HIA

\makeatletter
\define@key{bpsymb}{pcscale}{\def\pcscale{#1}}% about 0.7 (of em) (of em, ≈scriptfontsize)
\define@key{bpsymb}{loafwdscale}{\def\loafwdscale{#1}}% about 0.7 (of em)
\define@key{bpsymb}{loafsidescale}{\def\loafsidescale{#1}}% about 0.425 (of em)
\define@key{bpsymb}{linewidthscale}{\def\linewidthscale{#1}}% about 0.04 (of em)
\define@key{bpsymb}{bpnoisy}[true]{\csname bpnoisy#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

%% Notice the use of **em** units for lengths: this ensures that if the document
%% font size is changed the symbol will still look as it should relative to surrounding text.
\NewDocumentCommand{\bpsetup}{O{}}{%
    \setkeys{bpsymb}{#1}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mksymb}{}{% Minus two points; Tweak any or all of the following to suit:
    \setlength{\loafdomeht}{0.25em}%
    \setlength{\loafsideht}{\loafsidescale em}%
    \setlength{\puffht}{0.15em}%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\normalfont\fontsize{\pcscale em}{\pcscale em}\selectfont\%}%
    \setlength{\loafhalfwd}{\loafwdscale\wd0}%
    \sbox{\bpbox}{%
        \smash{%
            \tikz[outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt,use Hobby shortcut]{%
                \path
                    (0,0)coordinate(A)
                        -- ++(\sideslope:\loafsideht)coordinate(B)
                        -- ++(180-45:\puffht)coordinate(C)
                    (2*\loafhalfwd,0)coordinate(I)
                        -- ++(180-\sideslope:\loafsideht)coordinate(H)
                        -- ++(45:\puffht)coordinate(G);
                    \coordinate (M) at ($(A)!0.5!(I)$);
                    \coordinate (X) at ([yshift=\loafdomeht]M |- G);
                \draw[line width=\linewidthscale em] (A) -- (B) .. (C) .. (X) ..
                    (G) .. (H) -- (I) -- cycle; % draw the loaf
                \node[] at ($(X)!0.5!(M)$) {\box0};% add the \%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bp}{s o}{% *=force regenerate; #2=[text to appear in \typeout] 
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
        {\ifbpnoisy\typeout{force generating new\IfNoValueF{#2}{, #2}}\fi\mksymb}%
        {\ifvoid\bpbox% no previous instance, make new
            \ifbpnoisy\typeout{is void, generating new\IfNoValueF{#2}{, #2}}\fi\mksymb
        \else% use previously made
            \ifbpnoisy\typeout{not void, using pre-made\IfNoValueF{#2}{, #2}}\fi%
        \fi}%
    \usebox{\bpbox}%
}%

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\parindent0pt

\title{BP Symbol \bp*[title]\ Test}
\author{S. G. Moye}

\begin{document}

\bpsetup[bpnoisy=true]

\maketitle

\thispagestyle{empty}

\section{BP symbol \bp*\ for use in recipes \& tables }

\begin{multicols}{2}
\foreach \S in {%
    tiny, % `tiny` gives error, division by 0, using `quick Hobby shortcut`
    scriptsize,
    footnotesize,small,
    normalsize,large,Large,LARGE,huge,Huge}{%
    \S: \begingroup\csname\S\endcsname\bp*\par\endgroup
}
\columnbreak
New skeleton:

\begingroup
\setlength{\loafdomeht}{0.1in}% height above D--F
\setlength{\loafsideht}{0.5in}%% AB=HI
\setlength{\puffht}{0.1in}% =BC=CD=FG=GH
\setlength{\loafhalfwd}{0.225in}%=0.5AI

\tikz[baseline,every node/.style={font=\tiny}]{%
    \path
        (0,0)coordinate(A)node[left]{A}
            -- ++(\sideslope:\loafsideht)coordinate(B)node[left]{B}
            -- ++(135:\puffht)coordinate(C)node[left]{C}
        (2*\loafhalfwd,0)coordinate(I)node[right]{I}
            -- ++(180-\sideslope:\loafsideht)coordinate(H)node[right]{H}
            -- ++(45:\puffht)coordinate(G)node[right]{G};
        \coordinate (M) at ($(A)!0.5!(I)$);
        \coordinate (X) at ([yshift=\loafdomeht]M |- G);
        %
        \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (X) -- (G) -- (H) -- (I) -- cycle;
        \node at (M) {M};
        \node at (X) {X};
}
\endgroup
\end{multicols}

This is a test \bp[start]
\bigskip

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
This is a bunch X\bp X of bla bla bla to take up a certain amount of useless space. This is some text XO\bp OX with a symbol in it.\footnote{A BP symbol \bp*[fn]\ in a footnote, and this is another \bp[fn2]: Note that the symbol has been scaled to match the prevailing font size for footnotes. Also note the first use in the footnote: \texttt{\string\bp*} to force rescaling.} This is \bp\ a bunch of bla bla bla to take up a certain amount of useless space. This is in contrast to saying, for example, that a given flour has 14\% protein. This is a bunch \bp\ of bla bla bla to take up a certain amount of useless space.
\end{minipage}%

\bigskip

\begingroup
\footnotesize
\begin{tabular}{llll}
INGREDIENTS& WEIGHT& VOLUME& \bp*\\\hline
High-gluten flour*&290\,g&2 cups&100\\
Butter, cold&145\,g&⅔ cup&50\\
$\cdots$\\
Eggs, cold&120\,g& 2 ea&41.38\\
Whole milk, cold&65\,g&¼ cup& 22.41\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\footnotesize*\emph{\strut Be sure your bread flour is 12.5\% to 13\% protein.}


\end{document}



I woule probably drop D and F and use bezier curves and polar coord on the support points instead

The fontawesome5 package contains a bread-slice symbol. It is a filled symbol, but maybe you can overlay the % in white over it.

B and D, and symm., are obsolte: in and out will do. // 0deg is right, or east. If you go in=30deg, go  out=150 (180-30). // At C you want inout angles of 90/270. // It may suffice to use A, B and E only. // Bezier have a wider range, but also are harder to visualize before compile and need more space in standalone.

unrelated to your actual question but why is 145g of butter 50 BP of 250g of flour? I must be missing something:-)

@DavidCarlisle Very sloppy of me. Thanks and corrected.

Yet the amount of liquid depends on various characteristics of the flour, including age, and the environment. There's not an exact relationship between weight of flour and weight of liquid. This is true regardless of how you measure (though obviously there's even more variation if you measure by volume).

@DavidCarlisle I was confused about the same thing. The recipe seems to be the Sablée Brioche on page 274 (available in the reading sample), where the mass of the flour actually is 290 g. Then all the percebntages work out.

@sgmoye ^^^ ah can you fix the table in the question:-)

@DavidCarlisle Done, again -- apparently I did not save the correction the first time.

@DavidCarlisle And again...

@cfr Well, yes, to a an extent it is true that the variable nature of flour itself will have some impact on the amount of fluid required. That variation is far smaller than that arising out of the density of the flour.

@daleif Could you please expand on your comment? I assume that you refer to using \usetikzlibrary{hobby}...

@sgmoye no, to the .. controls ++(ang:len) and ++(ang:len) .. syntax.

@daleif Ah. Your mention of Bézier started me wondering: Why not let Hobby do the work? (Update coming in a bit...)

@sgmoye never seen the hobbyy library before. And I like to be able to control the curve pieces at each step.

@daleif  I believe that is possible, after a fashion, though I have not penetrated the documentation sufficiently to say more.

@daleif hobby uses the Hobby algorithm to calculate smooth curves. It's definitely worth knowing, though you wouldn't want to use it for everything because the calculations are expensive. (There is a quick function, too, however.)

@daleif Yes, the calculations are expensive, so I use an lrbox to write-once, use-many.

I did try use quick Hobby shortcut in the very last block of code (Update 2) but got an error I can't explain: ERROR: Package PGF Math Error: You've asked me to divide 0.0' by 0.0', but I cannot divide any number by 0.0' (in '--1.5708* 0.00000/(0.00000+ 0.00000)').`

I simplified your loaf and then redefined your \bp command to take any TikZ options an optional argument. For example:

Here is your table and code:

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[papersize={5.5in,8.5in},margin=0.6in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec,tikz}

\tikzset{
    loaf/.style={ 
        inner sep=5pt,
        path picture={
            \node[inner xsep=7pt, inner ysep=6.5pt](inbound) at (path picture bounding box){};
            \draw[thick, looseness=.8, #1](inbound.30) to[out=90, in=0] (inbound.90) 
                to[out=180, in=90] (inbound.150) to[out=270, in=150] ++(2pt,-2pt)[rounded corners=1pt]
                -- (inbound.240) -- (inbound.300)[sharp corners]
                -- ([shift={(-2pt,-2pt)}]inbound.30) to[out=30, in=270] cycle;
        }
    },
    loaf/.default={}
}

\newsavebox{\bpbox}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\bp}[1][]{\tikz[baseline=(Loaf.text)]{\node[loaf={#1}](Loaf){\%}}}

\begingroup
\small
\begin{tabular}{llll}
INGREDIENTS& WEIGHT& VOLUME& \bp[brown, fill=brown!20]\\\hline
High-gluten flour*&250\thinspace &2 cups&100\\
Butter, cold&145\thinspace g&⅔ cup&50\\
$\cdots$\\
Eggs, cold&120\thinspace g& 2 ea&41.38\\
Whole milk, cold&65\thinspace g&¼ cup& 22.41\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\footnotesize*\emph{Be sure your bread flour is 12.5\% to 13\% protein.}

\end{document}


How about this simple code (uses pure pdfLaTeX)? I used an arc for the top loaf and enabled rounded corners for the bottom two corners. A tiny percent sign is placed inside the loaf with tight boundaries (i.e. no inner sep or outer sep).
You might want to experiment with the scale; I eyeballed it so that the total height of the loaf is approximately the height of the font. To make things more precise, I smashed the symbol to height and depth zero and artificially gave the symbol the height and depth of the letter X.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\bp}{\smash{\tikz[scale=.15]{
    \draw (-40:1) arc[start angle=-40, delta angle=260, x radius=1, y radius=.3]
    [rounded corners=1pt] -- (-.6,-1.8) -- (.6,-1.8) [sharp corners] -- cycle;
    \node[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] at (-90:1) {\tiny\%};
}}\vphantom{X}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}} \toprule
        INGREDIENTS & WEIGHT & VOLUME & \bp \\ \midrule
        High-gluten flour* & 250\,g & 2\,cups & 100 \\
        Butter, cold & 145\,g & 2/3\,cup & 50 \\
        \dots \\
        Eggs, cold & 120\,g & 2\,ea & 41.38 \\
        Whole milk, cold & 65\,g & 1/4\,cup & 22.41 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}\\
    {\footnotesize*\emph{Be sure your bread flour is 12.25\,\% to 13\,\% protein.}}
\end{table}

\end{document}


I also used the booktabs package, which seems like a good call for such use cases. The siunitx package might be worth a consideration, but honestly, the unit cup with plural cups is a bit difficult.
